# How to create a Service that acts as a singleton with NestJS

Tags: dependency-injection, singleton, nestjs

I am trying to create a Module that provdies a singleton service. Imagine a `QueueService`, simplest implementation would be a singleton service.

Reproducible repository: https://github.com/colthreepv/nestjs-singletons

**WALL OF CODE**

app.module.ts:

```js
@Module({ imports: [FirstConsumerModule, SecondConsumerModule] })
export class AppModule {}
```

firstconsumer.module.ts **and** secondconsumer.module.ts (they are identical):

```js
@Injectable()
class FirstConsumer {
  constructor(private readonly dependency: DependencyService) {}
}

@Module({
  imports: [DependencyServiceModule],
  providers: [DependencyService, FirstConsumer]
})
export class FirstConsumerModule {
  constructor(private readonly first: FirstConsumer) {}
}
```

dependency.module.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DependencyService {
  constructor() { console.log("Instance created") }
}

@Module({ providers: [DependencyService], exports: [DependencyService] })
export class DependencyServiceModule {}
```

**CODE DONE**

What I would like to obtain is having console.log `Instance created` just be posted once.
At the moment:

```
[NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
Instance created
Instance created
Instance created
[InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +16ms
[InstanceLoader] DependencyServiceModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[InstanceLoader] FirstConsumerModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[InstanceLoader] SecondConsumerModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +8ms
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In NestJS modules are the singletons and their providers are made to be singletons so long as they are provided from the same module. In your sample code you have your `DependencyService` in three different `providers` arrays for three different modules. What should be done instead is to **only** have it in the `providers` array of the `DependencyServiceModule` and the `exports` array as well. Then you only need to have the `DependencyServiceModule` in the `imports` array of the `FrstConsumerModule` and `SecondConsumerModule` and **do not** add the `DependencyService` to the `providers` array of either. Thanks to the being in the `exports` array, the provider is available to the module context already.

```js
@Module({
  providers: [DependencyService],
  exports: [DependencyService]
})
export class DependencyServiceModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [DependencyServiceModule],
  providers: [FirstConsumer] // notice no DependencyService class
})
export class FirstConsumerModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [DependnecyServiceModule, FirstCosnumerModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And with the above you'll only see one log of "Instance created" instead of two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TLDR: services in nestjs are singletons, but **ONLY** regarding a module. So if you want a _ThingService_ to be a single instance in all the app, you should create a module that instantiate said _ThingService_, and then exports it. In that way the _ThingService_ will only ever have a single instance

Comment: Excellent answer. For some reason this isn't made very clear in the Nest JS docs regarding modules and how to properly register / use them.

Comment: This does not seem to work for guards, am I right? I see them being instantiated multiple times, even when it's only added as a provider in a single module and properly exported

Comment: Correct, guards and other enhancers will be instantiated per use.